# Run WindowsForm from Empty Project in C++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I created an empty Project in C++ and I add Windows Form to it. I want run this form when I compile the program but it doesn't work and give an error

> error LNK1561: error entry point must be defined

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. Is there any provided project in Visual C++ 2012 Similar to Windows Forms Application in C#?

Comment: Nice job of language tag spamming. You got your attention that you wanted, although it might not be good attention.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels oh sorry, I tried to add any other tags like Empty Project , Windows Form but i couldn't send my question to website

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Jumping to conclusions isn't necessarily helpful. PLease don't attribute to malice etc.

Comment: @peterchen: what does this question have to do with Java? How is it even remotely related to programming with this language? He tagged a lot of languages, some of them now deleted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Nothing. But accusing people of malicous intent moves nowhere: either you are right: good for you, no benefit for the site. Or you are not: you have made the tone of the site less friendly. I would *suggest* remove wrong tags and be done with it. peace.

Comment: I said i am sorry , i just was horry and it wasn't good way for send the question, I am mad for did that, ok so sorry

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start a new Windows project (not console based).  You may want to delete all the crud that MS puts in, such as stdafx.h and precompiled headers.  This will allow your program to be GUI enabled.

Otherwise, switch to a different GUI framework. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I created other provided project like Win32Project or MFC App, but it don't work for me, i need a form base application that i'll add text box, button or etc. how can i create a form base application in C++?